# Internal github VCS intellij idea issue

Tags: git, svn, github, intellij-idea

At first I was using the version control system subversion on windows in the "origin / master" branch, after I changed my OS to ubuntu and started using git control system. After 2 successful commit, I saw that thread that I have a "head" "master" makes it possible for which I can not successfully to commit to the main branch. How to switch to branch "origin / master"?

[image: here is my image from idea]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a confusion between how git and SVN work.

SVN keeps a remote history and for each commit, it stores changes in the remote repository.

Git keeps a local history of each change. At commit time, changes are stored localy. So, if you want to "push" your local history, you have to do a git push. In intellij, several ways to do it, for example, right click on the project->git->repository->push (or ctrl+alt+k), check everything is ok in the window (you have to push to origin master) and push.
If you don't want to commit push in two steps, in the commit window, instead of commit, you have the possibility to commit and push (see the arrow right of the commit button.

If you need more details, here's the corresponding chapter in git book : http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Chapter 2 of this book is a good start to git so feel free to read it :)

Hope it helps